# Upload and Download excel file in Django

Tags: python, django, download, upload

I want to create a web frame work Where I want to upload the excel file and then save and download the same excel file. if same excel file is uploaded 2 or 3 times or more while downloading this files should be named with some sumbers or so? with a download button how can i Do this

I have written Upload code but I am not sure how to proceed with Download part can  anyone help

Views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
import openpyxl
import settings

def index(request):
    if "GET" == request.method:
        return render(request, 'myapp/index.html', {})
    else:
        excel_file = request.FILES["excel_file"]

        # you may put validations here to check extension or file size

        wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(excel_file)

        # getting all sheets
        sheets = wb.sheetnames
        print(sheets)

        # getting a particular sheet
        worksheet = wb["Sheet1"]
        print(worksheet)

        # getting active sheet
        active_sheet = wb.active
        print(active_sheet)

        # reading a cell
        print(worksheet["A1"].value)

        excel_data = list()
        # iterating over the rows and
        # getting value from each cell in row
        for row in worksheet.iter_rows():
            row_data = list()
            for cell in row:
                row_data.append(str(cell.value))
                print(cell.value)
            excel_data.append(row_data)

        return render(request, 'myapp/index.html', {"excel_data":excel_data})
```

index .html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
            Excel file upload and processing : Django Example : ThePythonDjango.Com
        </title>
    </head>
    <body style="margin-top: 30px;margin-left: 30px;">
        <form action="{% url "myapp:index" %}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <input type="file"
                   title="Upload excel file"
                   name="excel_file"
                   style="border: 1px solid black; padding: 5px;"
                   required="required">
            <p>
            <input type="submit"
                   value="Upload"
                   style="border: 1px solid green; padding:5px; border-radius: 2px; cursor: pointer;">
        </form>

        <p></p>
        <hr>

        {% for row in excel_data %}
            {% for cell in row %}
                {{ cell }}&nbsp;&nbsp;
            {% endfor %}
            <br>
        {% endfor %}
    </body>
</html>
```

urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('myapp.urls', namespace="myapp")),
]
```

Answer (score 0):

When the same file is uploaded more than once, new files will be named with an extended number or a random string. You can adjust it.

There are 2 ways to make a file available for downloading:

1. Store your uploaded files in a public place then use webserver (nginx, apache) to handle downloading. It's just like you serve static/media files of Django project using webserver. It's recommended. Look at this: [Deploying static files](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/static-files/deployment/)
2. In a django view, read the file's content then return it to client. It's not recommended.